# How can I use the same buildscript for Flash Builder 4 and Ant/Mvn?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4, maven, flash-builder

I'm setting up a build system for a Flash Builder 4 (Flex 4) based project; and I'm struggling to get a setup that compiles in the IDE the same as it does from the command line on the build server.

I come from a C# background; and my expectation is that I'll be able to create a "solution" with a collection of "projects" that I can compile from the IDE, or from the command line on the build server.

The best I've managed sofar is 2 separate build "scripts", a custom ant script for the build server, and the default Flash Builder IDE config based on a workspace; but this is making my DRY daemons jump around in fury.

Please can someone point me in the right direction :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395860/how-can-i-automate-the-building-of-a-flex-component-library/1398235#1398235) is probably the best workaround for this problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [flex-mojos](http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/) for your command line builds, then you can use the [flexbuilder mojo](http://sites.sonatype.org/flexmojos/flexmojos-maven-plugin/flexbuilder-mojo.html) to generate the Eclipse project files from your Maven build scripts.  I'm sure there are some rough edges with the process, but at least it's DRY.

You might also check out [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html).  It can open the Maven project directly, and will create the Flex facets and configuration from the Maven build script.  It will auto-detect when the `pom.xml` file changes, and prompt for re-import (which is nice).  You can enable auto-import, too.  The down side is that it doesn't have the profiler or nice GUI editor that Flash Builder has.

Comment: Looks like the Hellfire compiler does something similar - generates an ant build.xml from the Flash/Flex Builder "workspace" - http://bytecode-workshop.com/