# Compiling content of directories/wildcard to SWC using Flex compc ant tasks

Tags: apache-flex, ant, compc

Here is how I usually write the compile task:

```
    <compc keep-generated-actionscript="true"
        include-classes="Class1 Class2 com.package.Class3"
        output="${module.output.dir}/output.swc" fork="${flex.fork}" maxmemory="256m">
        <source-path path-element="${module.basedir}/src"/>
    </compc>
```

What I'm looking for is a way to compile the entire director of classes without having to specify each class. I'm sure there's already an option for that, but I couldn't figure out the exact syntax.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Rick Herrick, I found the answer:

```
    <compc output="${module.output.dir}/output.swc" fork="${flex.fork}" maxmemory="256m">
        <source-path path-element="${module.basedir}/src"/>
        <include-sources dir="${module.basedir}/src" includes="*" />
    </compc>
```

Taken from: [How can I automate the building of a Flex component library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395860/how-can-i-automate-the-building-of-a-flex-component-library)